# SSRS 2005 performance issue with export

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have some SSRS 2005 reports, hosted on a report server. When we try to export the reports to excel its taking more than usual time to download. The reports otherwise takes acceptably reasonable time to render.

When i ran SQL profiler against the report server found that, it internally is calling "ReadChunkPortion" sp thousands of times. I am assuming this has something to do with the pagination.

Can we conditionally disable pagination, while doing an export ? Appreciate any help/directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have luck changing the InteractiveHeight property to 0, as described in the last sentence [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156282%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). This may affect the way the HTML renders, though, so be aware of the impact it might have.

In my experience, SSRS exports to Excel are generally inefficient, and the bigger the dataset the more frustrating it gets. [It seems like there is little you can do to change this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e1add311-634c-4158-98cc-ef4c7fc72286/).

If setting the InteractiveHeight property doesn't work, and you really need the Excel export to run faster, you may just have to export to a .csv then open in Excel. Unfortunately, it requires more steps from the user, but depending on the size of your report, it could still be faster than sitting and waiting for the Excel export to complete.

Comment: Thanks. We had infact settled on the CSV solution, only thing is its hard convincing users to do the extra steps needed. Will try out the InteractiveHeight property.